# What is jQuery doing to "this" in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that a jQuery event handler usually binds `this` to the object that emitted the event. And I also know that in vanilla JS, `this` is the object that invoked the function.

However, I'm having trouble making sense of why the following code works. `this` appears to reference the `tour` object defined in the code, yet going by the jQuery event handler binding, `this` should be the clicked button or going by JS, it should be the `$("#tour")` object since it invoked on.

Where am I going wrong?

```
var tour = {
  init: function() {
    $("#tour").on("click", "button", this.fetchPhotos);
  },

  fetchPhotos: function() { 
    $.ajax('/photos.html', {
      data: {location: $("#tour").data('location')},
      success: function(response) {
        $('.photos').html(response).fadeIn();
      },
      error: function() {
        $('.photos').html('<li>There was a problem fetching the latest photos. Please try again.</li>');
      },
      timeout: 3000,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#tour').addClass('is-fetching');
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('#tour').removeClass('is-fetching');
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
  tour.init();
});
```

Comment: I would say "bind the object to `this`".

Comment: The value of `this` in a function is never automatically inherited from its enclosing lexical environment. That goes for the environment of its creation as well as the environment of its invocation. The `this` value is always determined by *how* the function is invoked.

Comment: *"...yet going by the jQuery event handler binding... or going by JS..."* When it comes to language semantics, there is no "jQuery vs JS" behavior. jQuery is just a JavaScript library. It has no ability to add extra behavior to the language. It's just that `this` can be manually set (whether by jQuery code, or your code), and that's what jQuery does when it invokes its handlers.

Comment: Updated : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21532923/1636522.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only use of `this` in that code is:

```
$("#tour").on("click", "button", this.fetchPhotos);
```

It is used in the following function:

```
  init: function() {
    $("#tour").on("click", "button", this.fetchPhotos);
  },
```

How that function is called will determine the value of `this`. It is called like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  tour.init();
});
```

So `this` is `tour`.

---

> yet going by the jQuery event handler binding, this should be the clicked button

No. `this` isn't used inside the event handler function. It is used to get a reference to the function that is passed as an argument and eventually used as that function.

> or going by JS, it should be the $("#tour") object since it invoked on.

No. It isn't used inside the `on` function, it is used to get a reference to the function that is passed as an argument to that function.

```
function a(argument) {
    this; // Value depends on how a is called
}

function b(argument) {
    a(this); // Value depends on how b is called
}
```

---

`fetchPhotos` (the event handler function) doesn't use `this` at all, but if it did, it would be the object on which the event fired (since that is how `jQuery.on` would bind it).

Answer (score 1):

The functions invoked are `tour.init` and `tour.fetchPhotos`.

---

`tour.init` is invoked on this line:

```
tour.init();
```

so inside its body, `this` will point to tour (meaning that `this.fetchPhotos` will be `tour.fetchPhotos`).

---

`tour.fetchPhotos` is invoked by the jQuery event system, when the button is clicked. Inside its body, `this` will point to `#tour`, the HTMLElement that fired the event.
You can log it to make sure:

```
fetchPhotos: function() { console.log(this) }
```

Comment: As one way of making sense of things: `this` is only going to change once you enter the body of a function. If you're adding an inline `function() { ...` statement to a method, then it's likely that `this` is going to change inside of there. But if you're just calling methods, passing arguments, and calling methods from the return values, then `this` is going to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whats being asked here. But I assume you're calling

```
tour.init();
```

which makes `this` a reference to your `tour` object, within the execution context of `init()`. Thats why you can reference `this.fetchPhoto` within there and passing over the function reference to `.on`.

Within the *event handler*, `this` **will be** a reference to the node with the id of `#tour`.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is understandable. When you do

```
$("#tour").on("click", "button", function() {
 // inner scope
});
```

The inner scope `this` will refer to the invoked objected, because the third parameter, the annonymous function, will be run *on* that.

In your example, however, `this.fetchPhotos` isn't being run *on* an anonymous function, instead it's the function itself. So `this.fetchPhotos` refers to the function `tour.fetchPhotos`.

```
fetchPhotos: function() { 
  // inner scope
});
```

Inside the inner scope here, however, `this` will refer to the invoked object again.

Had you instead done:

```
$("#tour").on("click", "button", function() {
  this.fetchPhotos();
});
```

Then you would run into trouble as `this` would no longer be referring to the `tour` object, but instead the object that triggered the event, i.e. the DOM element with ID `tour`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `this` refers to the object which owns the method :

```
var o = {};
o.m = function () {
    return this;
};
o.m(); // returns o
// since "return this" equals "return o"
```

But you can "redirect" `this` to another object like so :

```
var p = {};
o.m.call(p); // returns p
// since "return this" equals "return p"
```

Getting closer to your own scenario :

```
p.n = function (fn) {
    return fn.call(this);
};
p.n(o.m); // returns p
// since "return fn.call(this)" equals "return o.m.call(p)"
```

A bit twisted :

```
p.n.call(o, o.m); // returns o
// since "return fn.call(this)" equals "return o.m.call(o)"
```

---

Concretely, when you write `tour.init()`, this line :

```
$('#tour').on('click', 'button', this.fetchPhotos);
                                 ^
```

Is the same as this line :

```
$('#tour').on('click', 'button', tour.fetchPhotos);
                                 ^
```

Then (very (very!) roughly), `#tour` is bound to `fetchPhotos` by jQuery through the `call` function, which will result in something like `fetchPhotos.call($('#tour')[0])`.